# How to setup stop a malicious website from forwarding to my website (my website is built on gatsby and hosted on netlify)

Tags: redirect, gatsby, netlify

I have a malicious website that is redirecting to my website and I would like to stop that. Since my site is built on gatsby and hosted on netlify, the direct addition of the .htaccess file with the following rule does not work.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maliciouswebsite1.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maliciouswebsite2.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I tried used gatsby-plugin-htaccess with the following custom rule in gatsby-config.js, but it doesn't seem to be working either. Any suggestions or ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-htaccess',
      options: {
        custom: `RewriteEngine on 
           RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maliciouswebsite1.com [NC,OR] 
           RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maliciouswebsite2.com 
           RewriteRule .* - [F]`
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.htaccess` syntax is not compatible with Netlify. They have the concept of `_redirects` file. Read more about it [here](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/). Also you may find [gatsby-plugin-netlify](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify/) to be quite useful as it provides API for setting up redirects and guidelines for using `_redirects` file.